# Variance of the mean of independent (not IID) normal random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Say you've got $i=1:N$ observations, $X_i$.  Each observation is the mean of a Gaussian with an associated variance $Var(X_i)$. The variances are NOT identical.  The expectation of $X$ should simply be their mean $N^{-1}\displaystyle\sum X$.  The variance of the mean should be 
$$
Var\left(N^{-1}\displaystyle\sum X_i\right) = N^{-2}\displaystyle\sum Var(X_i)
$$
Is this correct?  I'm following the basic formula on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance), but I'm getting implausibly small variances.  Am I missing something?  The above formula is usually used in the context of equal variances, but it doesn't say anything about requiring equal variances.

Comment: The variances need not be identical.

Comment: Your wording is not totally clear (you have not defined $X$), but if the $X_i$ are independent with each having variance $\sigma^2_i$ then the variance of $\displaystyle \sum_i X_i$ is $\displaystyle \sum_i \sigma^2_i$ and the variance of $\displaystyle \frac1n \sum_i X_i$  is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_i \sigma^2_i$, which I think is what you intended...

Comment: ... If the original variances are are all equal to $\sigma^2$ then this simplifies to saying the variance of $\displaystyle \sum_i X_i$ is $n \sigma^2$ and the variance of $\displaystyle \frac1n \sum_i X_i$  is $\displaystyle \frac{\sigma^2}{n}$.  Take square-roots of variances for standard deviations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is so.   The random variables do not need to be identically distributed.   However the result requires the random variables to be *independent*.

Let ${\{(X_i, \mu_i, \sigma_i^2)\}}_{i=1}^N$ be a series of *mutually independent* random variables, their means, and variances.

Let $\bar X:=\tfrac 1 N \sum\limits_{i=1}^N X_i$ be the mean of the series (ie: the *sample mean*).

Then indeed the *expectation of the sample mean* is: $\mathsf E(\bar X) = \tfrac 1 N\sum\limits_{i=1}^N \mu_i$

And the *variance of the sample mean* is:$$\begin{align}
\mathsf{Var}(\bar X) ~=~& \mathsf {Cov}(\tfrac 1 N \sum\limits_{i=1}^N X_i,\tfrac 1 N \sum\limits_{j=1}^N X_j) 
\\[1ex] =~&\tfrac 1{N^2} \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N \mathsf{Cov}(X_i,X_j)
\\[1ex] =~& \tfrac 1{N^2} \sum_{i=1}^N \mathsf{Var}(X_i) & ^\dagger
\\[1ex] =~& \tfrac {1}{N^2} \sum_{i=1}^N \sigma_i^2
\end{align}$$

(† because $\forall i\forall j: \big[i\neq j ~\to~ \mathsf{Cov}(X_i,X_j)=0\big]$ due to independence.)

And indeed, as the count $N$ increases infinitely the *variance of the sample mean* will decrease vanishingly.   $~\lim\limits_{N\to\infty} \mathsf{Var}(\bar X)=0$

---

**PS:** This is *not* the mean of the sample variance, if *that* is what is confusing you.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my intuition.  I wonder if the variances that I'm getting are so small because the quantities that I'm dealing with aren't in fact independent...

Comment: What if the variances are not bounded? That is, I know $\mathbb{V}\text{ar}(\bar{X}) \to 0$ if $\mathbb{V}\text{ar}(X_i) < M$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$, but if the variance are unbounded does this result hold?